# How to provide command line arguments to the VS2015 Android Debugger?

Tags: android, debugging, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, googletest

I am working on a library that is supported on many platforms including Android. This library is unit tested with the Google Test infrastructure. I am currently using Visual Studio 2015's cross platform features to build, deploy and debug. The test suite is getting considerably large and it takes a while to run the whole thing. With the Google Test infrastructure, it is possible to pass a command line argument to filter out the tests to be ran (--gtest_filter...). For platforms such as Windows, PS4 and XboxOne, this is easy to achieve inside Visual Studio by setting it in Project Properties -->Configuration Properties --> Debugging --> Command Arguments. However for the cross-platform developpment projects and package (AndroidProj), this Debugger property doesn't seem to exist. Here'a snapshot of Android [Native-Activity Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5jTe.png).

I am aware that the Visual GDB extension offers a similar feature to the one I am looking for as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geBl5.png), but this is not a viable option as I would like to avoid paying for the extension license.

How can I provide command line arguments to the Android Debugger the same way I can do it for the Local Windows Debugger for example?

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine found the answer not too long after I posted this question. Here's how we solved our issue.

In VS2015, in the property pages of the Android cross-platform Package/App project (Androidproj), more precisely in the Debugging tab, there is the Launch Activity field. This field can be used to pass command line intent arguments. When you launch the debugger after installing the package, it will execute the following command:

**adb.exe am start -D -n com.YourPackageName/TheContentOfLaunchActivityField**.

In the Launch Activity field by default the launcher activity is specified (android.app.NativeActivity), but you can provide further intent arguments. A list of them can be found in this documentation:  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#IntentSpec.

In our situation, we needed to provide string data to our app (e.g.: --gtest_filter=*...*), so we used the intent argument -e extra_key extra_value.

Inside our main function we can retrieve the values of the extras using the following piece of code and some parsing (not shown). It uses the JNI (Java Native Interface).

```
        JNIEnv* env = NULL;
        state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0);

        Private::JNIObjRef nativeActivityObject(env, state->activity->clazz);
        jclass nativeActivityClass = env->GetObjectClass(nativeActivityObject.Get());

        jmethodID getIntentID = env->GetMethodID(nativeActivityClass, "getIntent", "()Landroid/content/Intent;");
        Private::JNIObjRef intentObject(env, env->CallObjectMethod(nativeActivityObject.Get(), getIntentID));            
        jclass intentClass = env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");

        jmethodID getExtrasID = env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "getExtras", "()Landroid/os/Bundle;");
        Private::JNIObjRef extrasObject(env, env->CallObjectMethod(intentObject.Get(), getExtrasID));
```